# Extruder Motor Not working during Printing

Tags: extruder, diy-3d-printer

I am a **newbie** trying to setup and configure a 3D printer following online YouTube videos and tutorials. I am trying to configure a **Hypercube Evolution 3D printer**.
I followed Tech2C videos (on YouTube) and was able to configure Marlin firmware to some extent. I am using Pronterface to send test codes and taking files from thingiverse.com for testing.

Configuration :

- CoreXY
- Board : Ramps 1.4
- Extruder Setup Type : Direct drive using Titan e3D
- All end stops, temperature sensors, heaters configured and verified.

What is working :

- X,Y,Z axis movement directly from panel.
- Homing is ok.
- Temperature sensors, heating bed and hot end as expected.
- Extruder motor working with **direct** on panel command.

What is not working :

- When I send a print file (taken from thingiverse.com), the X,Y,Z axis work but there is no extrusion what so ever. I have tried a lot of things but using files from thingiverse, the extrusion of filament is not there whatsoever. It's been 2 months trying to figure out whether the issue is in firmware or the file, however to no use.

Can anyone help me get out of this or point out where I can be going wrong?

Comment: Hi Mandeesh welcome to 3D Printing.SE! I've built a HyperCube Evolution, maybe you could share your configuration.h file (a link to it please) so we can have a look for you!

Comment: What slicer are you using to convert the STL files into g-code? Most printers cannot handle STL files directly. Also, is Pronterface communicating with the printer? Can you home the head from Pronterface, for example?

Comment: Check that the printer is not in debug (dry-run) mode.

Comment: Did you unzip the file, then slice the `.stl` into a `.gcode`?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
1) @0scar Link to configuration.h file (https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmYgCJyTo4vUjib-2QzINY1czbpe)

Comment: 2) @Mick Yeah I guess I took g codes direcly from online websites without slicing as per my printer. Now I am using Slic3r for the same. I have attached the sample file above which I am trying to print. Yes homing is working fine.

Comment: 3) @Trish Yeah I figured this our quite late actually and this may be the problem.

Comment: Never use someone else's g-code (except for manufacturer's test files supplied with the printer). Always create your own. Treat every printer as if it is unique, because it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as special unclear because it seems to be abandoned and some rather vial questions (like the slicer) have not been addressed. As such it is impossible to answer thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

If the extruder extrudes fine from the control panel, chances are there's a configuration problem somewhere. For example, check your extruder steps/mm in the firmware to make sure it's not a nonsensical value; check the slicer settings to make sure that the filament diameter, line width, and layer height are all correct; make sure you're not trying to extrude in volumetric mode without having configured volumetric printing in your firmware and slicer correctly; and finally check your temperature control settings. When I first set up my fleabay 3d printer, I couldn't get my printer to work because the hotend minimum shutoff temp (thermistor disconnect protection basically) was set to something like 195C and the print temperature was 180C. I had an almost identical issue when I changed my fan assembly and it started blowing on the wrong part of the hotend, causing the firmware to register that entirely too much energy was being put into the extruder. Check the minimum temps for both hotend and heated bed and see if one of them is tripping your failsafes and stopping the extruder before printing even begins.

Comment: wth the process described, OP might have forgotten to slice the object too... though then it should not work at all...